# Добавить ссылки на фото

Tags: jquery

Как прикрепить ссылку к каждому фото?

```js
var img = [
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567541_hi-tech-technology-processor-6748.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567613_hi-tech-technology-internet.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567593_hi-tech-technology-internet-629.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567660_hi-tech-tehnologii-internet.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567622_hi-tech-tehnologii-plata-ruka.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567671_hi-tech-tehnologii-glaz.jpg',
    'http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567723_hi-tech-technology-processor.jpg'],
    img_num = 1,
    slide_rand = 0, // Рандом анимация = 1 //Не рандом 0
    slide_def = 2; // Если не рандом анимация то // 0, 1 или 2 = тип анимации
function img_slider() {
    console.log(img_num);
    $('[data-img_slider]').append('<img data-img_f="' + img_num + '" src="' + img[img_num] + '">');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (slide_rand == 0) {
            slide_def = 2;
        } else {
            slide_def = getRandomInt(0, 1);
        }
        switch (slide_def) {
            case 0:
                $('[data-img_f="' + img_num + '"]').show(400);
                break
            case 1:
                $('[data-img_f="' + img_num + '"]').slideDown();
                break
            case 2:
                $('[data-img_f="' + img_num + '"]').fadeIn();
                break
        }
        var img_r = img_num;
        if (img_num == 0) {
            img_r = img.length;
        }
        img_r = img_r - 1;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('[data-img_f="' + img_r + '"]').remove();
        }, 400);
        if (img_num == img.length - 1) {
            img_num = 0;
        } else {
            img_num = img_num + 1;
        }
    }, 400);
}
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(img_slider, 5000); // Время смены картинки // Не меньше 1000
});
```

```css
.img_slider {
    background: #8BB9F7;
    border: 1px solid #4072B4;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    height: 382px;
    width: 598px;
}
.img_slider img {
    border: 1px solid #4072B4;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 380px;
    width: 596px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_slider" data-img_slider="img_slider">
    <img data-img_f="0" src="http://d0gmatist.pro/uploads/posts/2015-04/1428567541_hi-tech-technology-processor-6748.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Берём

```
append('<img data-img_f="' + img_num + '" src="' + img[img_num] + '">')
```

И оборачиваем в `<a>`

```
append('<a href="'+ link + '"><img data-img_f="' + img_num + '" src="' + img[img_num] + '"></a>')
```